# Minimum price of fence around field

Tags: calculus, optimization

so I encountered this problem:

A rectangular area of $800$ square feet is to be enclosed by a fence and
then divided down the middle by another piece of fence. The fence
down the middle costs $\$2.00$ per foot, while the fence on the perimeter
costs $\$2.00$ per yard. Find the minimum possible cost for the fence.

I don't see what variables I need to make a function. Any hints ?

Thanks.

Comment: @Arthur Rimbaud The actual length, width are not known a priori, only the area is known. Also the rectangle is divided into 4 equal parts by centerlines and you choose an L shaped $ \frac34$ piece to fence, right?

Answer (score 0):

Let a be the length and b the width of the rectangular (in yards). Therefore the perimeter of the rectangular is $P=2a+2b$. One yard costs $\$2$. Thus the costs for the perimeter are $2\cdot (2a+2b)$. Additional you have to add the costs for fence down the middle, which has the length b. One feet costs $\$2$. That means, that 1 yard costs $3\cdot \$2=\$6$. In total you have the cost function  $$f(a,b)=2\cdot (2a+2b)+6b$$

The constraint is, that the area has 800 square feet. This is the same as $9\cdot 800=7,200$ square yards. Using the formula for the area of a rectangle we get the equation $a\cdot b=7200$. Solving for a we get $a=\frac{7200}{b}$.

You can insert this expression for a in $f(a,b)$ and then optimize $f(b)$ by calculating the derivative w.r.t b and set it equal to zero. Then solve for b. I think the rest you will manage. But if you have questions, feel free to ask.